# How to use a loading spinner for two async tasks consecutively

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, async-await, loading

Currently I have two independent async tasks making different web requests. When an async task is executed a loading spinner is shown. Now I should add a second async task to the first one, where the second depends on the first.

My main problem is the loading spinner, while summing up the two async calls. There is a fadeout animation on *Hide()* which is set to 0.5 seconds. Thus the spinner is shown two times for a short period time, which looks kind of ugly. If I skip the animation I get a flicker effect.

Perhaps I'm wrong and I should move to normal synchronous requests, but I don't want to block the UI thread. I don't know what I should search for. This is what I would currently do and is a simplified version:

```
public async void showList()
{
    List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();
    carList = await GetCarListTask();
    List<string> manufacturers = extractIDs(carList);
    List<Manufacturer> manufacturerList = await GetManufacturerListTask(manufacturers);
    Table.Show(carList, manufacturerList);
}

public async Task<List<Car>> GetCarListTask(){
    LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay ();
    List<Car> carList = new List<Car>();

    try{
        loadingOverlay.Show();
        carList = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetCarList());
        loadingOverlay.Hide();
        return carList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        alert.Show("Something went wrong");
        loadingOverlay.Hide();
    }

    return carList;
}

public async Task<List<Manufacturer>> GetManufacturerListTask(List<string> manufacturerID){
    LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay ();
    List<Manufacturer> manufacturerList = new List<Manufacturer>();

    try{
        loadingOverlay.Show();
        manufacturerList = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetManufacturerList(manufacturerID));
        loadingOverlay.Hide();
        return manufacturerList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        alert.Show("Something went wrong");
        loadingOverlay.Hide();
    }

    return manufacturerList;
}
```

As you can see the *LoadingOverlay()* is created independently for each request and depends on the current view. *Show()* in fact is a replacement for `this.NavigationController.View.InsertSubviewBelow(loadingOverlay,this.NavigationController.NavigationBar)` and the only central place would be the *AppDelegate*, but I don't think it has access on each navigation controller I use (modal views, popover, ...).

How should I solve this issue?

**Edit:**

Currently I'm not displaying the second loading spinner. It would be interesting what happens if the user is faster than the request ... So should I make the second call synchronous?

Another option which would come to my mind would be to redesign the [*LoadingOverlay()*](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) in a way that the flicker wouldn't be that much obvious. The nicest solution though would be to have a loading class which displays the loading spinner the whole time until all successive requests have been finished. But I don't know how such a centralized instance would look like. A simple solution would be to summarize the two calls into one method, but you have to be aware of the return type.

Comment: Use an integer that you increment when you start a task and decrement when a task finishes. When the count goes from 0 to 1 show the spinner. When the count goes from 1 to 0 hide the spinner. For all other values do nothing.

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks for your response. The thing which I still don't know is how to display the spinner on the current view. The *AppDelegate* would be the central place but it has only access to my main navigation controller. If I pop a modal view on top I create a new navigation controller. How should I display the spinner on the new created navigation controller?

Comment: I assume that you would pass the view where you wanted the overlay from the view controller that was initiating the asynchronous tasks.

Comment: That would be an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why you can't just move the showing/hiding logic to the calling method:

```
public async Task ShowListsAsync()
{
  LoadingOverlay loadingOverlay = new LoadingOverlay ();
  loadingOverlay.Show();
  try
  {
    List<Car> carList = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetCarList());
    List<string> manufacturers = extractIDs(carList);
    List<Manufacturer> manufacturerList = await Task.Run(() => manager.GetManufacturerList(manufacturers));
    Table.Show(carList, manufacturerList);
  }
  catch
  {
    alert.Show("Something went wrong");
  }
  finally
  {
    loadingOverlay.Hide();
  }
}
```

Perhaps the example is oversimplified and there's some reason this won't work.

Also, as a side note:

> I have two independent async tasks making different web requests

Web requests are asynchronous by nature. If you're using something like `HttpClient`, it should be simple to expose asynchronous versions of `GetCarList`/`GetManufacturerList` from `manager`. This would remove the need for `Task.Run`:

```
List<Car> carList = await manager.GetCarListAsync();
List<string> manufacturers = extractIDs(carList);
List<Manufacturer> manufacturerList = await manager.GetManufacturerListAsync(manufacturers);
```

Comment: Now I restructured my code after your proposal. The `WebRequest` is used in my case. You're right the web requests are aynchronous but I don't know what I should change on the library so that I get the asynchronous version.

Comment: @testing: I'd recommend using the [`HttpClient` nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http), which [supports Xamarin](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/11/13/pcl-and-net-nuget-libraries-are-now-enabled-for-xamarin.aspx).